# Help with formula field

Tags: custom-object, formula, formula-field, date

I have a custom object called Project. Within this object I have two important date fields – Finance Expiry date (`Finance_Expiry_Date__c`) and Contract Expiry date (`Contract_Expiry_Date__c`).

These two dates don’t always correlate. Priority is given to the date that is closest to expiry.

I want to create a formula field (`Priority Date field`) which will show the date that is closest to expiry.

In summary:

- If `Finance_Expiry_Date__c` is less than `Contract_Expiry_Date__c`,
  then `Finance_Expiry_Date__c` becomes the priority date.
- If `Contract_Expiry_Date__c` is less than `Finance_Expiry_Date__c`,
  then `Contract_Expiry_Date__c` becomes the priority date.
- If `Finance_Expiry_Date__c` is missing,
  then `Contract_Expiry_Date__c` becomes priority date.
- If `Contract_Expiry_Date__c` is missing,
  then `Finance_Expiry_Date__c` becomes priority date.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: IF (Finance_Expiry_Date__c < Contract_Expiry_Date__c, Finance_Expiry_Date__c, Contract_Expiry_Date__c)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After countless hours, I finally got it to work.

```
    IF( ISBLANK(Finance_Expiry_Date__c) = TRUE, Contract_Expiry_Date__c, 
    IF(ISBLANK(Contract_Expiry_Date__c) = TRUE,Finance_Expiry_Date__c, 
    IF(Finance_Expiry_Date__c < Contract_Expiry_Date__c, 
    Finance_Expiry_Date__c, 
    IF(Contract_Expiry_Date__c < Finance_Expiry_Date__c, 
    Contract_Expiry_Date__c 

    ,Contract_Expiry_Date__c 
    ))))
```

Comment: omg at least check the other answers

Comment: I did....but it didn't solve the issue as described.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to learn how to use formulas by reading [tutorials](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/point_click_business_logic/units/formula_fields) on trailhead.

Anyway, if you want to check if a field is empty, you can use the `ISBLANK()` function.Also you can check if a date is inferior to an another by using the `<` sign. The `IF()` condition allows to return a date if the condition is true and another date if the condition is fale. Finally, the `OR()` condition allows you return true if one of the condition is met.

So here's the code for your formula:

```
IF( OR(Finance_Expiry_Date__c < Contract_Expiry_Date__c, ISBLANK(Contract_Expiry_Date__c)) , Finance_Expiry_Date__c, Contract_Expiry_Date__c)
```

**Note**

This formula doesn't include a check to verify if the date is already expired or not. I don't know if you need it in your requirements.